# Tracking the mouse relative to starting drag position HTML5, Ember

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, ember.js

Starting off of this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/DYnNH/) I'd like to output the coordinates of the draggable object, as it's dragged, relative to its starting position, which is always {0,0}.  I know I can log the beginning and end drag events like:

```
DragNDrop.Draggable = Ember.Mixin.create({
    attributeBindings: 'draggable',
    draggable: 'true',
    dragStart: function(event) {
        var dataTransfer = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
        dataTransfer.setData('Text', this.get('elementId'));
        console.log('begin coordinates: (0, 0)');
    },
    dragEnd: function(event) {
        console.log('end coordinates');  
    }
});
```

So I have two problems:

1.How do I get the mouse coordinates?

2.How do I continue to output the mouse coordinates until the dragEnd function is called?

Edit:

For 1. I can now get the mouse coordinates using:

```
DragNDrop.Draggable = Ember.Mixin.create({
    attributeBindings: 'draggable',
    draggable: 'true',
    dragStart: function(event) {
        var dataTransfer = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
        dataTransfer.setData('Text', this.get('elementId'));
        console.log('begin coordinates: ', event.originalEvent.pageX, event.originalEvent.pageY);
    },
    dragEnd: function(event) {
        console.log('end coordinates: ', event.originalEvent.pageX, event.originalEvent.pageY);  
    }
});
```

But I still am not sure how to continually output the current mouse coordinates, rather than only one when the drag starts and once when the drag ends.

Comment: event.pageX and evet.pageY will give the mouse position.

drag event will continue to output the mouse coordinates

Comment: When I do `console.log('begin coordinates: ', event.pageX, event.pageY);` I get "begin coordinates: undefined, undefined"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
DragNDrop.Draggable = Ember.Mixin.create({
    attributeBindings: 'draggable',
    draggable: 'true',
    dragStart: function(event) {
        var dataTransfer = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
        dataTransfer.setData('Text', this.get('elementId'));
        console.log('begin coordinates: ', event.originalEvent.pageX, event.originalEvent.pageY);
        },
        // track the drag
        drag: function(event) {
            console.log('tracking coordinates: ', event.originalEvent.pageX,  event.originalEvent.pageY); 
        },
        dragEnd: function(event) {
            console.log('end coordinates: ', event.originalEvent.pageX, event.originalEvent.pageY);  
        }
});
```

Comment: How do you do this without ember?

Answer (score 0):

This code shows the coordinates of the mouse on drag

HTML

```
<div id= 'draggable'></div>
<input type = 'text' value = 'test' id='myInput'/>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $('#draggable').draggable();
    $('#draggable').on('drag' , function(event){
        $('#myInput').val(event.pageX + ',' + event.pageY);
    })
})
```

CSS

```
#draggable
{
    background-color:#EEE;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/PwFTv/)